# How to implement search bar In list view data Retrieve from local json file

Tags: flutter, dart, searchbar

Hello friend I am retrieve json data in my list view this json file inside my assets folder now I want implement search bar in my flutter application please help how to resolve this this issue its very important part in my app I have 500+ words in my flutter application so user search specific word through search bar any expert is here who can help me

```
    import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:hebrew/dictinary/Meaning.dart';
class Dictionary extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DictionaryState createState() => _DictionaryState();
}

class _DictionaryState extends State<Dictionary> {

  List data=[];
  List searchword=[];
  Future<String>loadjsondata()async{
  var jsonText=await rootBundle.loadString('assets/hebrew.json');

setState(() {

  data=json.decode(jsonText);


});
  print(jsonText);
}

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  setState(() {
    loadjsondata();
  });
  }

  bool issearching=false;

 void _filtwewords(value){

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(

          title:!issearching ?Text('Hebrew Dictionary')
            : TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              _filtwewords(value);
    },
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.search,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          hintText: "Search Words...",
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
    ),

    actions:<Widget> [
      this.issearching ? IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {

            this.issearching = false;
          });
        },
      )
          : IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.search),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            this.issearching =true;
          });
        },
      )

],
        ),


        body:Padding(
          padding:EdgeInsets.all(5),

          child: new ListView.separated(
             separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
             ),
             itemCount:data==null ? 0 :data.length,
             itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
               return Padding(
                 padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                 child: Column(
                   crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                   children: [

                     SizedBox(height: 10,),
                     GestureDetector(
                       onTap: () {
                         Navigator.push (context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>Meaning(data[index]['eng'],data[index]['hebrew'],data[index]['urdu'])));
                       },
                       child: Text(data[index]['eng'],style: TextStyle(
                           fontSize: 15
                       ),),
                     ),

                   ],

                 ),

               );
             }
              ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: my question is how to implement search filter  for searching words

Comment: I don't have any model class

Comment: @pskink my problem implement searchbar

Comment: @markanthony you can add the search bar on the app bar or you can use column and in that place, textfield and your listview this will be fine

Comment: @pskink your link is not working

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede will give any simple example or will you modify my code

Comment: @pskink yes it says page not found

Comment: @markanthony you want only UI right?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede no searchbar code

Comment: @markanthony you don't have any model class? and also want to implement search with listview right?

Comment: @markanthony kindly please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just made a code for search data using the **local JSON file**. First I created an empty `list` and all data in that list one by one and created a listview. After that created a `TextField` and check if `textfield` is empty then show full data else added **search data** in another list and show this data on `listview`

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
      ),
      home: SelectionScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SelectionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _selectionScreen();
  }
}

class _selectionScreen extends State<SelectionScreen> {
  List fullData = new List();
  List searchData = new List();
  TextEditingController textEditingController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocalJsonData();
  }

  getLocalJson() {
    return rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');   // Read your local Data 
  }

  Future getLocalJsonData() async {
    final responce = json.decode(await getLocalJson());
    List tempList = new List();
    for (var i in responce['data']) {
      tempList.add(i);   // Create a list and add data one by one 
    }
    fullData = tempList;
  }

  onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {
    searchData.clear();
    if (text.isEmpty) {    // Check textfield is empty or not 
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }

    fullData.forEach((data) {
      if (data['Title']
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .contains(text.toLowerCase().toString())) {
        searchData.add(data);   // If not empty then add search data into search data list 
      }
    });

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: InkWell(
          child: Text("Search With Local Data"),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: textEditingController,
            onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: searchData.length == 0   // Check SearchData list is empty or not if empty then show full data else show search data
                ? ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: fullData.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  spreadRadius: 2,
                                  offset: Offset(2, 2))
                            ]),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Post",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 2,
                            ),
                            Text(fullData[index]['Title'])
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: searchData.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  spreadRadius: 2,
                                  offset: Offset(2, 2))
                            ]),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Post",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 2,
                            ),
                            Text(searchData[index]['Title'])
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my local data.json file

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Title": "ABC",
      "Body": "And it takes nsuscipit follow accepted lightly with nreprehenderit discomfort may be the entire nnostrum of the things that happens is that they are extremely"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Title": "CDF",
      "Body": "And it takes nsuscipit follow accepted lightly with nreprehenderit discomfort may be the entire nnostrum of the things that happens is that they are extremely"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Title": "EFG",
      "Body": "And it takes nsuscipit follow accepted lightly with nreprehenderit discomfort may be the entire nnostrum of the things that happens is that they are extremely"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Title": "ABCD",
      "Body": "And it takes nsuscipit follow accepted lightly with nreprehenderit discomfort may be the entire nnostrum of the things that happens is that they are extremely"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Title": "PQR",
      "Body": "And it takes nsuscipit follow accepted lightly with nreprehenderit discomfort may be the entire nnostrum of the things that happens is that they are extremely"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Title": "RNDS",
      "Body": "And it takes nsuscipit follow accepted lightly with nreprehenderit discomfort may be the entire nnostrum of the things that happens is that they are extremely"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Title": "qwer",
      "Body": "And it takes nsuscipit follow accepted lightly with nreprehenderit discomfort may be the entire nnostrum of the things that happens is that they are extremely"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Title": "asdad",
      "Body": "And it takes nsuscipit follow accepted lightly with nreprehenderit discomfort may be the entire nnostrum of the things that happens is that they are extremely"
    }
  ]
}
```